# Cannot connect large numbers of multithreaded Python sockets (timeout error)

Tags: python, sockets

I'm writing a port scanner in Python, and the basic code looks like this:

```py
import socket
import sys
import threading

def scan_port(host, port, timeout):
    addr = str(host), int(port)
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    conn.settimeout(float(timeout))

    try:
        conn.connect(addr)
        print(f'- {port} open')
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'- {port} closed: {error!r}')
    finally:
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = sys.argv[1]
    pmin = int(sys.argv[2])
    pmax = int(sys.argv[3])

    threads = []

    for port in range(pmin, pmax+1):
        args   = [host, port, 1.0]
        thread = threading.Thread(target=scan_port, args=args)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

When I run this script on a single port, it always connects:

```sh
$ python scantest.py google.com 80 80
- 80 open
```

But when I run it on a large sequence of ports (at least 100), it always fails (with a generic "timeout" error):

```sh
$ python scantest.py google.com 1 100
- 1 closed: timeout('timed out')
- 2 closed: timeout('timed out')
- 3 closed: timeout('timed out')
- 4 closed: timeout('timed out')
# etc...
```

Is there some quirk of Python that prevents me from multithreading large numbers of socket connections, or am I missing some basic hurdle? I'm running this on Windows 8, if that helps. Thank you.

**Edit:** Judging from further research there simply seems to be a limit on how many socket connections a system can attempt at once. I've re-implemented this script with a `ThreadPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.futures` module and it's significantly improved reliability (at the cost of speed).

Comment: Does the timeout error come for all ports including 80? When trying to do a port scan on google via nmap it says only ports 80, 443, 554 an 7070 are open.

Comment: Yes, every port results in a timeout error, even ports we know for a fact are open.

Comment: @G3bE, looks like `554` and `7070` are also closed. So it's obvious